# What is a good reference for the normalization of analytic spaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I know how to define the normalization for a (algebraic) scheme, but how to define the normalization for a complex analytic space? My goto reference for analytic spaces is Griffiths' and Harris' *Foundations of algebraic geometry*, but I didn't find anythink in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reduced spaces, you could look at Chapter 8 in Grauert and Remmert's [*Coherent analytic sheaves*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-69582-7), or Remmert's Chapter 1, §14 in [*Several complex variables VII*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-09873-8).

In the latter reference, the normalization is constructed as the analytic spectrum
$$\operatorname{Specan} \widehat{\mathcal{O}}$$
where the *sheaf of normalization* $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}$ is the subalgebra of the sheaf $\mathcal{M}$ of meromorphic functions such that $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_x$ is the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_x$ in $\mathcal{M}_x$ for every $x \in X$. The fact that $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}$ is coherent is a theorem of Cartan and Oka; see §14.4 in Remmert's chapter for more historical background.